# Adding variable to list in prolog

Tags: list, variables, io, prolog, addition

I'm trying to work out how to add a name to a list in Prolog by prompting the user for the name then grabbing that list from the function, but I'm not sure how append works in this scenario:

```
test:-
    addname(Names),
    write(Names).

addname(Names):-
    write('Enter name followed by . (s. to stop)'),
    read(Name), nl,
    (Name = 's') ->
        true; %% exit procedure
        append(Names, Name, New),
        addname(Names).
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
get_names(Names) :-
    writeln('Enter name followed by . (s. to stop)'),
    read(Name), 
    add_name(Name, Names).

add_name(s, []) :- !.

add_name(Name, [Name | Names]) :-
    get_names(Names).
```

Usage:

```
?- get_names(Names).
Enter name followed by . (s. to stop)
|: 'John'.
Enter name followed by . (s. to stop)
|: 'Mary'.
Enter name followed by . (s. to stop)
|: s.
Names = ['John', 'Mary'].
```